# Immutability vs thread safety

Tags: immutability

Java immutable classes can be created by declaring it by

1. Declaring class final.
2. Declaring  all member fields final.
3. With no setters.

If there are no setters and class is declared final why should we set members final?

And also, Can i say, if a class is Immutable means it is thread safe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutable objects are thread safe, but why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303532/immutable-objects-are-thread-safe-but-why)

Comment: .If there are no setters and class is declared final why should we set members final? this is my major question here

Answer (score 1):

> If there are no setters and class is declared final why should we set members final?

To avoid the internal state to be modified *internally*. The following class looks immutable from the outside and we expect a call to `getBar()` to be side-effects free (it means **whenever** in time we call this method, we expect the **same** result, also known as *determinism*). However it's not, because calling `doThing()` has a side-effect on `bar`.

```
public final class Foo {
    private int bar;

    public Foo(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public int getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void doThing() {
        //do some things

        //increment bar for some reason
        bar++;
    }
}
```

If `bar` was `final` the code above wouldn't compile.

> Can i say, if a class is Immutable means it is thread safe?

Not necessarly but in many cases yes.